# Can't build in batchmode on remote linux machine

Tags: c#, android, linux, unity-game-engine, remote-server

I have an unusual problem when build on remote machine.

Target is Android and i try build application on remote server (Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4, unity: unity-editor-5.3.5f1+20160525_amd64.deb).

And what I see:

```
 /opt/Unity/Editor/./Unity
-batchmode
-projectPath
/home/jenkins/sources/client
-executeMethod
Assets.Scripts.Other.Git.BuildTools.BuildProject
-buildLocation
/home/jenkins/builds
-buildTarget
Android
-contour
Developer
-builderName
Jenkins
-quit
-logFile
/home/jenkins/log/01.log
Successfully changed project path to: /home/jenkins/sources/client
/home/jenkins/sources/client
UpdateMenuTitleForLanguage: 10
Using libudev for joystick management


Importing game controller configs
Loading GUID <-> Path mappings...0.000212 seconds
Loading Asset Database...0.000523 seconds
FMOD failed to get number of drivers ... An error occured that wasn't supposed to.  Contact support. 

(Filename: /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Audio/AudioManager.cpp Line: 533)

Audio: FMOD Profiler initialized on port 54900
AudioManager: Using Unknown: NoSound Driver
AssetDatabase consistency checks...0.048590 seconds
Build target platform 'Android' could not be used.

(Filename: /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Src/Application.cpp Line: 673)


Aborting batchmode due to failure:
Fatal error! Build target platform 'Android' could not be used.
```

It looks as if the sound card is not installed on the remote machine, but it was found there. Like the the video card, too.
Google advised to install pulseaudio...

Result log below:

```
mono profile = '/opt/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/lib/mono/2.0'
Initialize mono
Mono path[0] = '/opt/Unity/Editor/Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/opt/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/lib/mono/2.0'
Mono path[2] = '/opt/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityScript'
Mono path[3] = '/opt/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/lib/mono/2.0'
Mono config path = '/opt/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/etc'
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,defer=y,address=0.0.0.0:56679
Forcing GfxDevice: Null
NullGfxDevice:
   Version:  NULL 1.0 [1.0]
   Renderer: Null Device
   Vendor:   Unity Technologies

BATCHMODE ARGUMENTS:
/opt/Unity/Editor/./Unity
-batchmode
-nographics
-projectPath
/root/sources/client
-executeMethod
Assets.Scripts.Other.Git.BuildTools.BuildProject
-buildLocation
/root/builds
-buildTarget
Android
-contour
Developer
-builderName
Jenkins
-quit
-logFile
/root/builds/log_17.txt
Successfully changed project path to: /root/sources/client
/root/sources/client
UpdateMenuTitleForLanguage: 10
Using libudev for joystick management


Importing game controller configs
Loading GUID <-> Path mappings...0.000424 seconds
Loading Asset Database...0.074730 seconds
Audio: FMOD Profiler initialized on port 54900
AudioManager: Using ALSA: default
AssetDatabase consistency checks...3.354307 seconds
Build target platform 'Android' could not be used.

(Filename: /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Src/Application.cpp Line: 673)


Aborting batchmode due to failure:
Fatal error! Build target platform 'Android' could not be used.
```

I think I have tried everything, but the result remains the same.

On the local machine with a similar configuration everything works fine.

Had met anyone else with a similar problem and if so, how you solved it?

Comment: Just checking, did you try what the first google result says? (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/switching-platform-in-batch-mode-in-unity-5-0-solved.311572/) and also `pulse-audio` is installed? (https://community.unity.com/t5/Audio/Several-Unity-games-segfault-at-quot-FMOD-failed-to-get-number/td-p/2432330/page/2) and more obscure FMOD things (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/several-unity-games-segfault-at-fmod-failed-to-get-number-of-drivers-when-pulseaudio-isnt-running.369943/)

Comment: thanks for the advice.
Yes, I tried it before.
Result same.
The problem seems unsolvable, because It seems that the remote machine configuration does not meet the requirements. However, I would like to highlight the key problems.

Comment: Does https://medium.com/@h0lycattle/running-unity3d-in-a-virtualized-headless-ubuntu-environment-1adf95c05994#.x2zz0rjbb help?